# How extract the .rar files through ANT script

Tags: ant

How to Extract the `.rar` files through ANT script and multiple files?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's anything native in ant or Java to handle RAR files.  Maybe you can `<exec>` the unrar command [from here](http://home.gna.org/unrar/)?

Comment: agree with you, I've found similar answer in the ant-user list: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/200606.mbox/%3C44A15217.9080202@mdl.com%3E